# IBM iからFTPのMGETコマンドでファイルを取得した際に文字化けが発生する

Tags: windows, 文字化け, ftp

WindowsからIBM i上に存在するソースコードをFTPで一括して取得しようと考えていますが、
mgetコマンドを使用するとファイル中の日本語部分が文字化けします。
getコマンドを使用した場合はこの問題は起こらず、mgetコマンドを使用したときのみ起こります。
これを文字化けしないで取得する方法はないでしょうか？

実行したFTPコマンドは以下の通りです。

```
ID
PASSWORD
QUOTE SITE NAMEFMT 1
QUOTE TYPE B 1
CD /QSYS.LIB/QXXXLIB.LIB/TEST.FILE/
PROMPT OFF
MGET *.MBR
QUIT
```

上記コードの`MGET *.MBR`の部分を`GET HELLO.MBR`に変えると文字化けが起こりません。
また、IBM i側のファイルの文字コード(CCSID)は5035です。

---

追記
debugモードでのログを記載します。

```
ftp> debug
デバッグ オン。
ftp> quote site namefmt 1
---> site namefmt 1
250  NOW USING NAMING FORMAT "1".
ftp> quote type b 1
---> type b 1
200 REPRESENTATION TYPE IS SHIFT JIS KANJI.
ftp> cd /qsys.lib/QXXXSRC.lib/TEST.file/
---> CWD /qsys.lib/QXXXSRC.lib/TEST.file/
250 "/QSYS.LIB/QXXXSRC.LIB/TEST.FILE" IS CURRENT DIRECTORY.
ftp> prompt off
対話モード オフ。
ftp> mget *.mbr
---> TYPE A
---> PORT 192,168,***,***,195,100
---> NLST *.mbr
---> TYPE A
200 REPRESENTATION TYPE IS ASCII NONPRINT.
---> PORT 192,168,***,***,195,101
200 PORT SUBCOMMAND REQUEST SUCCESSFUL.
---> RETR A.MBR
150 RETRIEVING MEMBER A IN FILE TEST IN LIBRARY QXXXSRC.
226 FILE TRANSFER COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY.
ftp: 197 バイトが受信されました 0.00秒 197000.00KB/秒。
---> PORT 192,168,***,***,195,102
200 PORT SUBCOMMAND REQUEST SUCCESSFUL.
---> RETR B.MBR
150 RETRIEVING MEMBER B IN FILE TEST IN LIBRARY QXXXSRC.
226 FILE TRANSFER COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY.
ftp: 197 バイトが受信されました 0.00秒 197.00KB/秒。
---> PORT 192,168,***,***,195,103
200 PORT SUBCOMMAND REQUEST SUCCESSFUL.
---> RETR C.MBR
150 RETRIEVING MEMBER C IN FILE TEST IN LIBRARY QXXXSRC.
226 FILE TRANSFER COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY.
ftp: 41 バイトが受信されました 0.00秒 41000.00KB/秒。
---> PORT 192,168,***,***,195,104
200 PORT SUBCOMMAND REQUEST SUCCESSFUL.
---> RETR D.MBR
150 RETRIEVING MEMBER D IN FILE TEST IN LIBRARY QXXXSRC.
226 FILE TRANSFER COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY.
ftp: 197 バイトが受信されました 0.00秒 197000.00KB/秒。
ftp> quit
---> QUIT
221 QUIT SUBCOMMAND RECEIVED.
```

Comment: 認証完了後(PASSWORDの後)、`DEBUG` を入れた上で、差支えのない範囲で動作ログを貼っていただければもう少し分かるかもしれません。

ただし、MGETは単に `RETR` コマンドを複数回発行するだけなので、GET / MGET で文字化けする / しないで違いがあるのであれば、ホスト側に何らかの問題があるように思われます。

Comment: @TatzSekine debugモードでのログを追加しました。ただ、おっしゃる通りRETRコマンドを複数回発行しているだけのようですね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ftp> quote type b 1
---> type b 1
200 REPRESENTATION TYPE IS SHIFT JIS KANJI.
```

まではうまくいっているようですが、当初の予想に反し、NLST でファイルのリストを取得した後、

```
---> NLST *.mbr
---> TYPE A
200 REPRESENTATION TYPE IS ASCII NONPRINT.
```

で ASCII モードになってますね。`quote type b 1` が FTP クライアントに type コマンドの亜種として認識されないので、よくよく考えれば不思議な動作ではないですね。

考えうる対処としては

1. binary で転送して、Windows 上で文字コード変換
2. `mget` の前後で発行するコマンドを細かく制御できる FTP クライアントを使う
3. `ls` コマンドを使ってファイルリストを取得し、それを自前でパースし逐次 get コマンドで取得するような .BAT なり PowerShell を書く
4. Ruby やら Python といった LL を使う

あたりでしょうか。ご自分の仕事環境で一番楽な方法を選べばいいと思います。

Answer (score 3):

`prompt off`と`MGET *.MBR`の間に`ascii`というコマンドを入れればうまくいきませんか。

これでうまくいかない場合、IBMにもっと具体的にどのコードで送ってほしいか指示する必要があるのですが、生憎windowsのftpクライアントにはそのようなものはありません。そういった場合、`quote`というコマンドを使って任意の文字列をホストに送ることができます。
問題は何を送ればいいか、ということなのですが、検索していたらAS400のftpの使い方というページがありました
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/html/as400/v4r5/ic2962/info/RZAIQTYPE.HTM#HDRRZAIQTYPE
この`TYPE B4R`を実行したときにホストに送られるものと同じものを送ればいいのですが、実機が無い場合、うまく転送できるgetのログやトレースなどから推定するか、`remotehelp`などを見ながらあれこれ試すしかありません。
仮に`TYPE B4R`を入れると`site mode b4r`というコマンドが送られるなら`quote 'site mode b4r'`のように使います。このあたりから、IBMのサポートに聞く方が早いという解が現実味を帯びてくると思います。

これをやってもだめな場合、それはクライアント側のgetとmgetの機能が違うということなのでftpコマンドを使う限りどうにもなりません。その可能性は決して低くないと思います。

Comment: asciiコマンドを追加→効果はありませんでした。
`quote 'site mode b4r'`　これは正しくないコマンドのようです。
正しくは`quote type b 4r`と思われます。
しかしながら、このコマンドを使用しても文字化けは発生したままでした。

IBMサポートへ問い合わせてみます。ご回答ありがとうございました。

Comment: quoteはあくまでも例なのでそれらしいのもを書いただけで内容の保証はありません。ここはメーカーのサポートではないのですから。そして、そもそも論として、ftpには文字コードに関する取り決めはなく、全部メーカー固有機能です。今getでコード変換がうまくいっているのはたまたまうまくサーバとクライアントのデフォルト機能が一致しただけなのでそれ以外のことができる保証も一切ありません。

Answer (score 1):

Windows側で文字コードを別途変換出来る手段があるのであれば、バイナリモードでダウンロードした方が確実だと思います。

Answer (score 1):

自己回答
Windows側からIBM i側へ`mget`するのではなく、
IBM i側からWindows側へ`ltype c 943`コマンドを使用した後で`mput`することで
文字化けせずに転送することが可能。